# how to query external and internal storage together in android

Tags: android, storage, media

I want to get the list of all media files/songs together from memory card and phone memory. Is there any way to do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

#### Content Resolver way--> MediaStore.Audio

`Querying the Content Provider through Content Resolver`
`Implement proper ListView and add the data which you get after querying Content resolver to ListView via Adapter`

```
    String[] columns = { android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID,
    android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM };
    cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,columns, null, null, null);
    String[] displayFields = new String[] { MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM };
    int[] displayViews = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };
   setListAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, displayFields,displayViews));
```

---

#### Traditional Way :: Scanning SD-CARD for .mp3 files

Use below code to get the path to sdcard directory.

```
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String rootPath= root.getPath();
```

From rootPath location, you can build the path to any file on the SD Card. For example if there is an image at `/DCIM/Camera/a.jpg`, then absolute path would be `rootPath + "/DCIM/Camera/a.jpg".`

However to list all files in the SDCard, you can use the below code

```
String listOfFileNames[] = root.list(YOUR_FILTER);
```

`listOfFileNames` will have names of all the files that are present in the SD Card and pass the criteria set by filter.

Suppose you want to list mp3 files only, then pass the below filter class name to list() function.

```
FilenameFilter mp3Filter = new FilenameFilter() {
File f;
public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {

    if(name.endsWith(".mp3")){
    return true;
    }

    f = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+name);

    return f.isDirectory();
  }
};
```

Comment: these link will help you for proper understanding http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Media/ListtheMediaStore.htm